# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known No DNS issue

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to learn network scripting via Python. I am trying to extract device names from file "Device_List" and then ssh to the device, executing a command on it and printing the output.

It works fine when I use IP address in the file however it does not if I use a hostname. I tried this on an **Ubuntu Trusty** as well as **Mac OSX**.

I get the following error:

```
FWIP = socket.gethostbyname(name)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I am able to resolve the hostname on both machines so it is not a DNS issue.
Moreover, if I input the device name from keyboard instead of file, it works fine.

Could you please help me find the issue?

My Code:

```
import datetime
import paramiko
import socket
import time
import sys
import getpass

with open("Device_List") as dev:
    for name in dev:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        Uname = raw_input("Username : ")
        Pw = getpass.getpass()
        print "Connected to ", name
        FWIP = socket.gethostbyname(name)
        ssh.connect(FWIP, username=Uname,password=Pw)
        remote_conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
        remote_conn.send("set cli pager off\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        command = raw_input("Enter Command to run : ")
        remote_conn.send(command + "\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        output = remote_conn.recv(65534)
        print output
        print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        print "Moving Onto Next Device..."

    print "Device List Over"
```

Comment: I did some packet capture and found that when I am passing the device name to the socket.gethostbyname, I see "^J" appending to the hostname. For eg: my file has hostname abc-01@domain.com(letters and numbers both), when I run the script, I see the query is being sent as abc-01@domain.com^J, which obviously fails. Could someone please help me truncate the ^J ? Thank You so much in advance...

Comment: You should find the origin of this ^J. Is this a single symbol or two? If you are in hurry, the duct tape would be     name = name[:-1]  to erase the last symbol, and     name = name[:-2]  to erase the two last symbols. (This code should be put before anything you do with name)

Comment: Thank You so much. This worked! However I am still not sure how ^J is getting appended. The system is appending ^J as one character.

Comment: You're welcome :) That's strange. I have never seen ^J to appear at the end of each line before, but I know that in Windows new line is indicated by "\r\n", and in Linux - by just "\n". This causes the problem when you make a text file in Windows (e.g. with Notepad) and the open it in Linux - "\r" appears at the end of each line, very much like as in your case. Hope this info will help.

Comment: @Андрей Череватки : After running this, except for the first entry in the list, all others are failing. I have found out that "^J" is appended only to the first line in a multi-line text file. So if I have an IP as the first entry and subsequent entries has hostname the script runs fine without stripping the last character. I am very new to Python and I am not able to find the reason as to why "^J" is appended to the first item of the list. Any ideas are most welcome... Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Андрей Череваткин : Also I am using Pycharm community edition on an Ubuntu Trusty. I created the text file via PyCharm. I'll try to delete this file and create a file via vi in Ubuntu and try again. Will update you soon.

Comment: @Андрей Череваткин : I deleted the old file, created a new .txt file with first line as the hostname and it failed again. It added "^J" at the end...

Comment: Maybe you could put the file here somehow?

Comment: I don't find a way to upload my file here

Comment: How about cloud storages, like Dropbox? You just have to put a link here

Comment: I put a duct tape by including the following in my code: if name[0]: name = name[:-1] Now the complete list works. Will continue my investigation on ^J though :) @АндрейЧереваткин : Thank you for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over lines in a text file, e.g. your

```
with open("Device_List") as dev:
    for name in dev:
```

the default I/O subsystem always includes the '\n' line ending character. One reason is that this way you can tell when a text file ends *without* ending the final line.

Get used to using (e.g.) `dev.rstrip()` when you don't want that.